# How to get the date that order got complete in WooCommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, status, orders

I am using this code to get an array of order ids of WooCommerce:

```
$query = new WC_Order_Query( array(
    'limit' => 10,
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'return' => 'ids',
) );
$orders = $query -> get_orders();
```

Now I want to create a loop and get the date that order got complete. There is a way to get the modified date, but I only want to get the completed date. Any help?

--- Edited ---

Actually I want to get orders that got complete in the last 30 days. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    $query   = new WC_Order_Query( array(
        'limit'      => 10,
        'orderby'    => 'date',
        'order'      => 'DESC',
        'return'     => 'ids',
    ) );
    $orders  = $query->get_orders();

    $completed_dates = array();
    foreach ( $orders as $order_id ) {
        $order                       = wc_get_order( $order_id );
        $completed_dates[ $order_id ]    = $order->get_date_completed();
    }
    echo '<pre>$completed_dates:-';
    print_r( $completed_dates );
    echo '</pre>';
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works just fine. Is there any fastest way to get orders that got complete in the last 30 days? Something like in the query using `date_completed`?

Comment: $orders = wc_get_orders(array('post_status' => 'wc-completed')); This will return all completed odrers - There is date_before and date_after query options

Answer (score 0):

From Woo´s documentation:
( https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/wc_get_orders-and-WC_Order_Query )
Date
date_created, date_modified, date_completed, date_paid

Accepts a string. Date queries use a standard format:

'YYYY-MM-DD' - Matches on orders during that one day in site timezone.

'>YYYY-MM-DD' - Matches on orders after that one day in site timezone.

'>=YYYY-MM-DD' - Matches on orders during or after that one day in site timezone.

'<YYYY-MM-DD' - Matches on orders before that one day in site timezone.

'<=YYYY-MM-DD' - Matches on orders during or before that one day in site timezone.

'YYYY-MM-DD...YYYY-MM-DD' - Matches on orders during or in between the days in site timezone.

'TIMESTAMP' - Matches on orders during that one second in UTC timezone.

'>TIMESTAMP' - Matches on orders after that one second in UTC timezone.

'>=TIMESTAMP' - Matches on orders during or after that one second in UTC timezone.

'<TIMESTAMP' - Matches on orders before that one second in UTC timezone.

'<=TIMESTAMP' - Matches on orders during or before that one second in UTC timezone.

'TIMESTAMP...TIMESTAMP' - Matches on orders during or in between the seconds in UTC timezone.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).